# SSIS - Convert a varchar field to unique identifier

Tags: sql, ssis, business-intelligence

Thanks in advance for this everyone.

I have a source column which is a Business Key with a VARCHAR format in my source database. All fields contain only numeric values. (It's horrible)

I want to extract that data, transform the format and load into a unique-identifier format.

I can extract the data I need, the  format transformation is performed but is not correct in order to load data into the unique-identifier column which I have prepared in a separate DW.

As there are numerous other columns to import i am hoping to be able to do this in SSIS.

I welcome any questions or answers.

Thanks

Will

Comment: Any chance you could show us what this business key looks like?

Comment: "is not correct" isn't really a problem we can help you with.   What's wrong with it, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not try to convert your business key to GUID. GUIDs are pure surrogate keys, its main advantage is being unique throughout distributed system landscape. Generate GUID in the DataFlow itself. I have done it the following way:
* Create a Script Transformation in DataFlow with following output parameters[image: following output parameters] 
* Script source to create GUID

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
// Create a Globally Unique Identifier with SSIS
    Row.GUID = System.Guid.NewGuid(); 
}
```